# Mounting a Gardena retractable garden hose(115ft) to inside garage

Tags: drywall, mounting, studs, hose, drywall-anchor

What would be the proper way (or should I even attempt) to mount this inside my garage walls? most of the information I could find was related to mounting the unit on the outside of the house. The screw locations on the mounting bracket also make it impossible to secure on a single stud.

The unit itself is about 45lbs

Thank You

[image]

Comment: Would add a piece of plywood or some 2x4s to the wall for mounting.  Drywall does not like moisture(condensation) and any leaks which you might not notice soon will be on the inside instead of outside the house(where it does not matter as much).

Comment: butterfly dry wall anchors will do it

Comment: @Ruskes  If it just hung there, they probably would work, but this is something that will having pulling forces on it also.

Comment: @crip659, nothing more complicated that that should be the answer, you should turn your comment into one.

Comment: @TigerGuy   Good ideas happen at same time.

Comment: "inside my garage walls" I'm envisioning this between the siding on the outside and the drywall on the inside, replacing some insulation. I'm sure that's not what you intended to say, but... once imagined I can't unsee that.

Answer (score 9):

The recommended space is outside of the house because of possible leaks.

To mount inside on a stud wall with drywall, would screw a piece of plywood or some type type of wood to two studs.

Can mount the holder to the plywood with screws.

To limit the possibility of leaks, place a notice nearby to remind yourself or anyone to shutoff the valve supplying water to the hose after use.

Comment: Thanks, I'll definitely give it a try !

Comment: Some additional advice to this answer. I'd suggest using some "penny washers" between the screws and the plastic of the mount. I've seen a few people do something like this where the weight of the hole reel is enough to pull the screw heads through the hole in the plastic. Some washers larger than the heads of the screw will prevent this.

Comment: @scotty3785  That is a good idea.  Plastic hose reels usually don't have that great of a life expediency.   Every little bit helps.

Comment: It's not just the weight of the hose (already heavy enough), but also people do tend to unreel only a short section and then run water through it...and it's not even a static load at that point.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to mount it inside on drywalls...

Get a 20 inch wide plywood maybe 4 ft long, that you paint to protect from accidental water exposure.

Screw the plywood between two 2x4 to get stability.

Now you can screw the hose reel on to it.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend a yard hydrant installed in the middle of your yard and keep the hose and hose reel near the [yard hydrant](https://www.walmart.ca/en/ip/Water-Source-YH-4-4-ft-Yard-Hydrant/PRD5YLF8W15OW85?skuId=5YLF8W15OW85&offerId=F061F707F94B4025A9D73CB15F009C59&region_id=201500&utm_medium=paid_search&utm_source=google&utm_campaign=always_on&cmpid=SEM_CA_112_TQ2KKELEI9_71700000072956255_58700006365555361&utm_id=SEM_CA_112_TQ2KKELEI9_71700000072956255_58700006365555361&gclsrc=aw.ds&&gclid=Cj0KCQjw39uYBhCLARIsAD_SzMSPYA2-nCKDwCeDPqz8aqrtY1ohzy__90O20_UScVHCUc6M_AMlwCwaAr3wEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds).  It is a nice clean look and you aren't dealing with 115' of hose.

Answer (score 2):

If you're dead set on mounting this inside the garage, a simple solution is to cut a piece of plywood (3/4" should do) about 2" wider and taller than that plastic mounting bracket. Attach the plywood to a stud using some lag bolts with the heads of the lag bolts lined up in the center of the stud and ensuring that vertically, they fall into the spaces in the back of the bracket, roughly where the green circles are.

Once your plywood is lagged to the stud, use the mounting screws included with the bracket to attach the bracket to the plywood. The screws should hold just fine in the 3/4" plywood and if they happen to go through the plywood and extend into the drywall behind, it won't matter. That won't do any more significant damage to the drywall, nor will it help or hinder their holding power.

[image: updated version of OP's picture showing rough location of lag bolts]

You could, of course, paint the plywood to match the wall color if you'd like to make it less obvious.

---

I'll reiterate the advice of others, though, to mount this outside in case there are leaks as it's always preferable to have leaking water outside rather than inside.

Comment: Upvoted for the suggestion that the plywood doesn't need to span two studs.